# Access class fields from partial class

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I'm currently in a scenario in which I have to make use of partial classes.
In this partial class I have a few methods that need to address fields in the other class.

for example

**Edit: I'm sorry: the first class is already declared `partial`!**

```
public partial class myClass
{        
    private string _myString;

    public string myString
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set { _myString = value; }
    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class myClass
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        myString = "newString";
    }
}
```

The compiler says `myString` doesn't exist in the partial class!

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few things you need to fix with the code you posted:

When using partial classes in C# **all** parts of the class must be declared as partial classes

You have:

```
 public class myClass {}
 public partial class myClass {}
```

Which needs to become:

```
public partial class myClass {}
public partial class myClass {}
```

Secondly, you're trying to set:

```
myString="newString";
```

but `myString` is a public property without a setter.

So either you add a setter when declaring `myString`:

```
public string myString
{
    get{ return _myString; }
    set { _myString = value; }
}
```

or just use:

```
_myString="newString";
```

in your second partial class file.

Answer (score 42):

A common problem is having the partial classes in different namespaces. Namespaces are part of the Class name, `namespace1.myClass` and `namespace.a.myClass` are handled as two completely seperate classes.

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), 
each part of a partial class should:

- have the `partial` modifier
- have the same class name
- be in the same namespace
- be in the same assembly or DLL
- have the same visibility (like public, private, etc)

Comment: I would like to add that if one partial implements an interface, the other partials should include the same declaration. The actual interface methods only need to be implemented in one of the files, but the partial class declarations need to match.

Answer (score 1):

When I put your code into Visual Studio I got a different error:

```
myString = "newString";
Error   Property or indexer 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.myClass.myString' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

If I change it to this, it works fine:

```
_myString = "newString";
```

**Edit:**

You **don't** need to mark a class as partial in both palaces, this compiles fine:

```
    public class myClass
    {

        private string _myString;

        public string myString
        {
            get { return _myString; }
        }
    }


    public partial class myClass
    {

        public void doSomething()
        {
            _myString = "newString";
        }

    }
```

Comment: While it might compile fine, in the documentation it says its required. Its probably a good idea to do it anyway to be consistent, and future proof.

Comment: I just followed what the forms designer does...naughty winForms designer!

Comment: I had the same problem until I noticed that my method was static. Duh!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both declaration refer to the same namespace, your first declaration does not contain the partial keyword:

> Using the partial keyword indicates
>   that other parts of the class, struct,
>   or interface can be defined within the
>   namespace. All the parts must use the
>   partial keyword. All of the parts must
>   be available at compile time to form
>   the final type. All the parts must
>   have the same accessibility, such as
>   public, private, and so on.public, private, and so on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/wa80x488(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to mark the class as `partial` in **both** places, not just one of them.