# Get value of partial class for other class

Tags: c#

I have a class partial.I want to get one value inside this class , Below code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public  String Main_Trunk;
        //...........
        public  class EXP
        {
            //How can i get value Main_Trunk ?? 
        }
}
```

How can i do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access class fields from partial class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132984/access-class-fields-from-partial-class)

Answer (score 1):

In C# you cannot access members of the enclosing class directly, therefore, the members need to be passed to the inner class, and the typical way of doing this is through the nested class's constructor.

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public String Main_Trunk;
    class EXP
    {
        string Inner_Trunk;
        public EXP(Form1 f1)
        {
            Inner_Trunk = f1.Main_Trunk;
        }
    }
    void Func()
    {
        EXP ei = new EXP(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, and please consider marking it as answer if it was the right answer to your question.